# Get only time from a string of more than one dateTime

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

I have a string which gets the dateTime as a GROUP from the database, so I get something like this

```
2017-10-20 05:00:00,2017-10-20 09:00:00,2017-10-20 07:00:00,2017-10-20 13:30:00,2017-10-20 16:00:00,2017-10-20 13:00:00,2017-10-20 06:00:00,2017-10-20 09:30:00,2017-10-20 10:30:00,2017-10-20 15:30:00,2017-10-20 17:00:00
```

Note that all of the dates are the same, i.e., 2017-10-20. Since I don't need to worry about the different dates. All I want is to simply extract the time from this string, and print it nicely like this

```
05:00, 09:00, 07:00, 13:30, 16:00 //and so on
```

I don't want the seconds, it would be unnecessary.

I tried using PHP's strtotime() function but it fails and gives 00:00:00 instead.

Any ideas? I am using Laravel as a templating engine.

Comment: Do you get those results literally, as a single string, or are you denoting array elements with your commas?

Comment: I'd probably just do a `str_replace('2017-10-20 ', '', [YOURSTRING]);`

Comment: @kerbholz the date won't be hardcoded, I will get different dates as a database result.

Comment: @zuif: ok, wasn't obvious to me from your question.

Comment: @George I get those results as a string. The reason being, I am using SELECT GROUP_CONCAT for my query, which apparently gives me this string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it within your SQL statement.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`dateColumn`, '%H:%i') FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

```
$dateTimes = '2017-10-20 05:00:00,2017-10-20 09:00:00,2017-10-20 07:00:00,2017-10-20 13:30:00,2017-10-20 16:00:00,2017-10-20 13:00:00,2017-10-20 06:00:00,2017-10-20 09:30:00,2017-10-20 10:30:00,2017-10-20 15:30:00,2017-10-20 17:00:00';
$dateTimesArray = explode(',', $dateTimes);
$timesArray = [];
foreach($dateTimesArray as $dateTime) {
    $timesArray[] = date('H:i', strtotime($dateTime));
}
$times = join(',', $timesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tGroup = "2017-10-20 05:00:00,2017-10-20 09:00:00,2017-10-20 07:00:00,2017-10-20 13:30:00,2017-10-20 16:00:00,2017-10-20 13:00:00,2017-10-20 06:00:00,2017-10-20 09:30:00,2017-10-20 10:30:00,2017-10-20 15:30:00,2017-10-20 17:00:00";

$retVal = "";
$dates = explode(",", $tGroup);
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $time = date('H:i', strtotime($date));

    // use this if you want to print AM/PM format
    //$time = date('h:i A', strtotime($date));

    $retVal .= $time . ", ";
}
echo trim($retVal," ,");
```